# Gulp not starting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, gulp

First time using Gulp this has been starting for the last 20 minutes, Is this normal, What can I do to speed it up? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtm8P.png)

**UPDATE**
Left it an hour and then closed it, Did not start.

Comment: your given gulp configuration would likely help quite a bit as without we can't debug why it wouldn't be starting

Comment: You may have just left off a signal (like a `return` statement) to tell gulp the task has finished.  But without your code, we can't help.